# Is there a way to Cancel Apple Subscriptions from a nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, in-app-purchase

i am trying to cancel some subscriptions created in ios app but from the server side.

Does anyone know how to make it from a node js server? i have the next data: paymentRecipt details and shared secret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 12, there is currently no way to cancel, modify, edit subscriptions on the server side for Apple IAP's. Apple places a lot of limits on In App Purchases. You also can't offer refunds, extended trial periods, etc. on the server side. Apple's system is very much what you see is what you get. There is very little flexibility in the system.

In short, there is no way to do this yourself. Your user must be the one to cancel the subscription on their own device.